# Designing multiple input software

Tags: event-handling

I'm looking for a way to high-level structure the software I develop (for Android, but that's not important here, I believe). My software is driven by events from sensors, user interactions, remote messages, and timer events. I'm afraid it's becoming a mess where I can't oversee what combination of inputs might cause problems.

A state machine would be nice, but there seem to be too many possible states. As a newbie, I do implement design patterns here and there. But I'm lost as to the overall design. How do I give a structure to all the "events" that keep streaming into my application?

Answer (score 2):

The "too many states" comment is just a reflection of your own observation, that it's a mess.

In a good design, you would decompose the system in multiple independent Finite State Machines. A 20-state system might be better represented by a 4-state and a 5-state system.

For instance, in your case you might be able to refactor all inputs into a single input queue. This queue would have its own state (empty, partially full, full) independent of the processing that happens further on.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into how robot software handles this. Robots face similar challenges.